# Why does Sodium Bicarb. Reduce Combustion Rate?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, home-experiment, combustion, reaction-control, fuel

In many common solid-propellant model rocket engines, Sodium Bicarbonate, $\ce{NaHCO3}$, is used to predictably regulate/limit the rate of combustion of the fuel. My questions are as follows:

1. What is the mechanism for this (reaction?)?
2. How would I know how much $\ce{NaHCO3}$ to add to the fuel for a certain reaction delay time?
3. Is $\ce{NaHCO3}$ somewhat unique in it's ability to do this, or is this something that many common chemicals can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of dry NaHCO3 to extinguish a fire works in two ways:

First, the smothering of the flame with CO2 and water per the decomposition reaction:

$\ce{2NaHCO3 ⟶ Na2CO3 + CO2 + H2O}$

Second, the decomposition reaction is endothermic, so it lowers the temperature of the fire. To quote [a source](https://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=6979.0):

> In an endothermic reaction heat must be continuously supplied and the reaction is not self-sustaining. Stop heating NaHCO3 and the decomposition will slow down and stop.

Answer (score 1):

When heated, $\ce{NaHCO_3}$ is easily decomposed and produces much $\ce{CO_2}$ in the chemical reaction : $$\ce{2 NaHCO_3 -> Na_2CO_3 + CO_2  +  H_2O}$$ and $\ce{CO_2}$ is a gas that tends to prevent Oxygen from maintaining the fire. As to your question 2, I have no idea how to solve it. And as to your question 3, $\ce{NaHCO_3}$ is by far the best compound and the cheapest. The other possibilities are the other alcaline bicarbonates, and apart from potassium bicarbonate, they are rather expensive.

Comment: I guess that rules out francium bicarbonate! ;-)

Comment: Which would vaporize from its own radiation anyway.  I've read in Wikipedia that magnesium hydroxide works too, by endothermically evolving water vapor.